# Angular 9 upgraded to Angular 14: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Crypto')

Tags: angular, typescript

We are upgrading Angular 9 application to Angular 14. Followed https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=9.0-14.0 upgrade instruction and all successfully completed, but after running ng serve command application do not load any content, it errors with below error.

Anyone encountered such issue, what is crypto has to do here?

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ORG",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --source-map=false",
    "start_dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration=dev_server --source-map=false",
    "build:dev_server": "ng build --configuration=dev_server",
    "build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=12288 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --source-map=false"

  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.5",
    "@ctrl/tinycolor": "^3.4.0",
    "@grapecity/ar-designer": "^15.2.0",
    "@grapecity/ar-viewer": "^14.2.2764",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@nrwl/angular": "9.2.4",
    "@types/device-uuid": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/raphael": "^2.3.1",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.2.7",
    "angular-xslt": "^0.2.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.4.0",
    "canvg": "^3.0.7",
    "chart.js": "3.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "2.0.0",
    "convert-units": "^2.3.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.1",
    "device-uuid": "^1.0.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "immer": "^7.0.0",
    "infinite-scroll": "^3.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-charts": "3.0.0-rc.5",
    "ng2-signalr": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-dynamic-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-print": "1.2.0-beta.6",
    "ngx-xml2json": "^1.0.2",
    "org-new-ui-el": "1.1.12",
    "popper.js": "1.16.0",
    "primeicons": "2.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "raphael": "^2.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-freeze": "^0.1.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "signalr": "^2.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "tui-image-editor": "^3.14.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.4.0",
    "xmldom-ts": "^0.3.1",
    "xslt-ts": "^1.1.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@nrwl/jest": "9.2.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "9.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.2",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jest": "25.2.3",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "25.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-html-report": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older version of Angular till v12, the object-hash worked without any trouble. But with v13 and v14, object-hash needed types package i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/object-hash.
After installing `npm i @types/object-hash`, Crypto error disappeared and application started working. I am still wondering why there is no compilation error and only runtime error, should be helpful to fix .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you step by step for upgrading angular to avoid a problem. Because from the documentation when you upgrade from 9 to 14 it shows a warning something like this

> Warning: We do not support migrating across multiple major versions at
> once. Please migrate each major version individually.

You can try from 9 to 10, 10...14

Comment: Yes, step by step, till 12 application was running after successful upgrade, 13 and 14 upgrade successful but application do not run.

Comment: have you tried to delete node_modules, package-lock.json, and npm install again?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming were talking about Crypto-JS, tested with Angular 14, it should work. Please post your package.json if you're still having issues after overlooking package.json.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "3.1.41",
    "core-js": "2.5.5",
    "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/crypto-data-lnexjs?file=package.json

Comment: Added in question. And app do not use any Crypto.

Comment: I don't see crypto-js in your package. What dependency is your app trying to reference?

Comment: Thats what not sure, which reference has dependency on Crypto and that got enabled in higher Angular.

Here the additional browser console log, __webpack___

 __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
__webpack_exec__ @ .*$:292
(anonymous) @ .*$:292
__webpack_require__.O @ chunk loaded:23
(anonymous) @ .*$:292
webpackJsonpCallback @ jsonp chunk loading:71
(anonymous) @ main.js:1

Comment: Found the dependency, there is custom package which has reference of object-hash